# Eclipse "return false;" html error

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, validation, jsp

I have been getting red markers on the file and the vertical bar because of "return false;" inside html tags on jsp's.

Is there any way to disable specifically this "return false;" verification.  Eclipse categorizes it as "Cannot return from outside a function or method".  I disabled validation, reinstalled eclipse, and did a whole bunch of things but I can't seem to find a way to remove it.  I don't want to disable the vertical tab annotations because I use it a lot.

How do I disable "return false;" validation?

-edit

Sorry I didn't include an example,

```
<form onsubmit="insertAbbr();return false;" action="#">
```

There's a bug in eclipse saying that his hasn't been resolved,

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353209

I'm using latest eclipse version. Thanks.

Comment: can you show the screenshot please?

Comment: In my experience Eclipse doesn't do a great job of validating JSP; I turn it off altogether. It'd still be a good idea to show an example of the HTML/JSP that causes the issue, and state which version of Eclipse you're using.

Comment: I updated it, see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go to preferences->validation and select JSP Syntax Validator. Then you can create custom filters for different situations. Try creating exclusion rules for Content Types: jspfragmentsource and tagsource. If you apply the exclusions one at a time, you can isolate the one that is bothering you and leave the others included. I wish I could be more specific, but I don't really have an example of the offensive code/marker to experiment with, so you will have to experiment for yourself. Good luck.

Comment: @Sam I found another relevent property sheet today while I was looking for something unrelated. I figured I would give you the heads-up, as it has been bothering me that this one was never resolved. It is web->jsp files->editor->validation. It lets you reduce the severity of different types of errors to warning or ignore. Here's hoping you can locate the right one for your problem ;-}

Comment: I unchecked "Report problems as you type" on (General->Editor) and that seems to have taken away the red stuff but it also disable a lot of validation...

Comment: Web->JSP Files -> Editor -> Validation didn't give me a solution for it, it seems like a strange bug.

Comment: Un-checking "Report problems as you type" seems to work, the only downside is that you have to save the file before the errors are pointed. The "return false;" issue seems to get fixed tho.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Client-side JavaScript Validator from the relevant Validation preference/property page.  That's the one that operates on web pages.  The JavaScript Validator, the one that's its own Builder, only deals with .js files.